# Create a new database in SQL Server 2008 R2, but it is not Blank

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

When I try to create new database in SQL Server 2008 R2, it was created completely, but it is not a blank and empty database, there are many tables that come from another database. I also tried specifying a different name for its `.mdf` and `.ldf` file, but nothing changed!

Would you please help me to know where is the problem?

Also, is there any command that would reset my database as a blank db?

Answer (score 6):

New databases are cloned from database `model`. Probably some accident polluted your `model` database (maybe a DDL script run in the wrong database). You should probably clean it up.

Comment: Thank you so much.
But how can I do that(clean it up)?

Comment: By deleting the stuff in it that you do not want to keep. Either manually or by scripting deletes for everything.

Answer (score 5):

Below is the significance of Model database from [BOL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186388.aspx) :

> The **model database** is used as the **template for all databases created on an instance of SQL Server**. Because tempdb is created every time SQL Server is started, the model database must always exist on a SQL Server system. The entire contents of the model database, including database options, are copied to the new database. Some of the settings of model are also used for creating a new tempdb during start up, so the model database must always exist on a SQL Server system.

Check for `model.sys.tables` looking for tables `where is_ms_shipped = 0` to find out user created tables and then :

- Check the table contents.
- Check with your dev/users/colleagues, etc just to make sure they are not used or are critical to your application functionality.
- **Back up the model database**.
- Rename or Drop the tables.